# Concat YYYYMMDDHHMMSS From Arduino DS3231

Tags: datetime, arduino, concatenation

I want to read the date/time info from a DS3231 real time clock and concatenate the result into a yyyymmddhhmmss format with minimal lines of code.  The following routines work fine to retrieve and print the data, but I can't figure out how to concatenate it into a single variable / string.

```
byte BCD2DEC(byte val){             //Ex: 51 = 01010001 BCD.  01010001/16-->0101=5 then x10-->50.  
  return(((val/16)*10)+(val%16));}  //         01010001%16-->0001.  50+0001 = 51 DEC

void GetRTCTime(byte *second, byte *minute,byte *hour,byte *DoW,byte *Date,byte *month,byte *year){
  Wire.beginTransmission(DS3231_I2C_Addr);  //Open I2C to RTC
  Wire.write(0x00);                         //Set reg pointer to 0x00 Hex
  Wire.endTransmission();                   //End xmit to I2C.  Tell RTC to send data.
  Wire.requestFrom(DS3231_I2C_Addr, 7);     //Get 7 bytes from RTC buffer
  *second = BCD2DEC(Wire.read() & 0x7f);    //Seconds. remove hi order bit
  *minute = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());           //Minutes
  *hour = BCD2DEC(Wire.read() & 0x3f);      //Hour 0-24 remove 2 hi order bits
  *DoW = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());              //Day of week (1Sun-7Sat)
  *Date = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());             //Date (1-31)
  *month = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());            //Month (1-12)
  *year = BCD2DEC(Wire.read());             //Year (00-99)
}
void printTime(){                           //Read & print data from RTC
  GetRTCTime(&second, &minute, &hour, &DoW, &Date, &month, &year);  //Get RTC data
  Serial.print(x);             //Print year 20xx.  Year 00-99
  if(month<10){Serial.print("0");}          //Print leading 0 if needed
  Serial.print(month, DEC);                 //Month as decimal
  if(Date<10){Serial.print("0");}           //Print leading 0 if needed
  Serial.print(Date, DEC);                  //Date (1-30)
  Serial.print(DoWList[DoW]);               //1Sun-7Sat (0=null)
  if(hour<10){Serial.print("0");}           //Print leading 0 if needed
  Serial.print(hour,DEC);                   //HH
  if(minute<10){Serial.print("0");}         //Print leading 0 if needed
  Serial.print(minute, DEC);                //MM
  if(second<10){Serial.print("0");}         //Print leading 0 if needed
  Serial.println(second, DEC);              //SS
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yyyymmddhhmmss is 14 characters.

Create a buffer for 15 characters (your text + terminating null character)

```
char buffer[15];
```

Fill the buffer with your text:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d\0", year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```

%d is a number, %02d fills the number up with leading zeros so it has at least 2 digits.

Print.

```
Serial.println(buffer);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Comment: Just to be clear with the OP, while this is less lines of code it is probably actually larger code that takes up more program space than the code in the question.  Less lines doesn’t always equate to smaller code.  sprintf is an expensive function.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried sprintf but could not get it right and went for other paths.  This gives me an array of characters.  "unsigned int datetimeresult = buffer.toInt();" would create a single integer from the characters, yes?

Comment: "could not get it right" bears no useful information.  not sure what you cannot get right, I gave you the solution. the only issue mentioned by Delta_G. It is expensive

Comment: No, I had tried it before I left the comment and could not make it work.  Your code works fine, thank you.